# Trabajar con OpenTok en Composer.JSON

Tags: php

tengo un proyecto de PHP y su estructura es la siguiente:

La carpeta principal se llama OpenTok, dentro de ella se encuentran dos archivos, el index.php y el composer.json y otra carpeta también llamada OpenTok que incluye todos los archivos del paquete. El problema es que cuando trato de generar una sesión de la siguiente manera me manda un error:

```
    <?php
    use OpenTok\OpenTok;

    $apiObj = new OpenTok($API_KEY, $API_SECRET);
    $session = $apiObj->createSession(array('mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED));
    echo $session->getSessionId();
?>
```

El error que me manda es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Class 'OpenTok\OpenTok' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenTok\index.php on line 4

Yo espero y puedan ayudarme a encontrar una solución. Saludos.

Agregando más información, el composer.json que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    {
    "name": "Opentok/Opentok",
    "description": "OpenTok is a platform for creating real time streaming video applications, created by TokBox.",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [
        "TokBox",
        "OpenTok",
        "PHP",
        "WebRTC",
        "video",
        "streaming"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ankur Oberoi",
            "email": "ankur@tokbox.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Community contributors",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "support@tokbox.com",
        "issues": "https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK/issues"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.0.0",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.7",
        "aoberoi/json-works": "~1.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.1",
        "phing/phing": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "OpenTok\\": "src/OpenTok"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estás usando un Framework o algo así vas a tener que incluir en la primera línea el `require 'OpenTok/autoload.php` o `include OpenTok/autoload.php` o generalmente el archivo donde está ubicada la clase que quieres instanciar / llamar:

```
<?php
require 'OpenTok/vendor/autoload.php';

use OpenTok\OpenTok;

$apiObj = new OpenTok($API_KEY, $API_SECRET);
$session = $apiObj->createSession(array('mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED));
echo $session->getSessionId();
```

Según la [documentación de OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/php/) el archivo `autoload.php` se encuentra del directorio `vendor`:

> This package follows the PSR-4 autoloading standard. If you are using composer to install, you just require the generated autoloader:
>   **require "/vendor/autoload.php"**;

Si estás usando un framework es normal que utilicen un archivo `autoload.php` para evitar lo primero.

**Edito:**

**Paso 0:**

Si utilizas Composer tendrás un archivo `composer.json` en tu directorio principal, sino, debes descargarlo desde aquí: http://getcomposer.org

**Paso 1:**

Añade automáticamente el paquete de OpenTok desde tu línea de comandos (ejemplo para Linux):

`$ ./composer.phar require opentok/opentok 2.3.x`

O añade en tu archivo `composer.json` dentro de `require:`

```
"require": {
    ...
    "opentok/opentok": "2.3.x"
    ...
}
```

**Paso 2:**

Si no utilizas Composer no importará el archivo `composer.json`. Entonces puedes descargar el paquete de OpenTok desde [aquí](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-php-sdk/releases) y referenciarlo en el archivo PHP que vayas a utilizar de la forma que te dije anteriormente:

```
<?php
require 'OpenTok/vendor/autoload.php';

use OpenTok\OpenTok;

$apiObj = new OpenTok($API_KEY, $API_SECRET);
$session = $apiObj->createSession(array('mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED));
echo $session->getSessionId();
```

Contános cómo vas hasta ahí. Suerte.

Comment: Y este archivo de donde lo saco, o donde se genera. Sinceramente no tengo mucha noción en esto. Se me a dificultado trabajar con OpenTok

Comment: En el directorio donde se encuentra el paquete OpenTok, supongo que es `OpenTok/OpenTok` debes seguir la siguiente ruta: escribir lo siguiente: `require OpenTok/OpenTok/vendor/autoload.php` en tu script.

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri, esto hará que puedas instanciar la clase `OpenTok` y utilizar sus métodos. Reemplaza (o compara) el código brindado por mi, por el tuyo.

Comment: Ok entiendo y de verdad muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, el problema es que ni siquiera se si estoy bien en el composer.json. Lo unico que hice fue pasar a la raíz de mi proyecto el que venía por default cuando descargue el SDK de OpenTok

Comment: Como mencioné en la respuesta, puse un enlace a la documentación: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/php/ con eso puedes guiarte desde el inicio de los pasos.

Comment: La documentación esta en Inglés, es por eso que acudi aqui.

Comment: Por eso lo expliqué detalladamente en la respuesta. La voy a modificar para que se se vea qué hacer desde el paso cero.

Comment: Creo que ya entendí un poco, además de la estrctura que mencione en un principio. Ya aparece dentro de la carpeta principal llamada OpenTok la carpeta vendor y dentro de ella varias carpetas y el archivo autoload , hago lo siguiente: require 'vendor/autoload.php'; Pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Poné `require '/OpenTok/OpenTok/vendor/autoload.php` y contame.

Comment: Veo que publicaste el archivo `composer.json` del paquete mismo. Pregunta, vos además del paquete de OpenTok, tenés un proyecto ¿verdad? Se debería ver algo así la ruta: `C:\xampp\htdocs\tuProyecto`

Comment: Me parece que lo correcto es esto, porque si lo coloco como lo mencionas además de ese error me aparece el siguiente:  Warning: require(Opentok/Opentok/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenTok\index.php on line 3

Comment: Exactamente lo tengo así , tengo el proyecto y dentro la carpeta de OpenTok que contiene las librerías del paquete

Comment: Bueno, dentro de tu archivo `index.php` referencia al archivo `autoload.php` donde se encuentre con: `require 'OpenTok/vendor/autoload.php'

Comment: Creo que ahora me confundí un poquito más, osea la ruta es la siguiente: C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenTok\OpenTok, ¿El composer.json y el vendor/autoload irán en la carpeta donde vienen las librerías de OpenTok?

Comment: Para empezar tu proyecto debería estar ubicado así: `c:/xamp/htdocs/tuProyecto` y dentro tener un `index.php` que llame a la ruta mencionada y la carpeta `OpenTok` que ya hablamos.

Comment: Si exacto, entonces el composer.json y la carpeta vendor irán en la carpeta del proyecto, no en la de OpenTok

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48507/discussion-between-maramal-and-guillermo-ricardo-spindola-bri).